# How to token-exchange between internal clients on behalf of already authenticated client in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, token-exchange

I am using Keycloak 17.0 with

```
keycloak.profile.feature.admin_fine_grained_authz=enabled
keycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled
```

The issue: I need to provide **refresh token** for a client on behalf of already authenticated confidential service account client. I need something very close to **internal to internal token exchange** like it's described [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#internal-token-to-internal-token-exchange). The only thing is that I need to make a token exchange call **without** `subject_token` parameter. Is it possible to have a client that will provide tokens for another internal clients without their authentication/tokens?

Comment: ' Is it possible to have a client that will provide tokens for another internal clients without their authentication/tokens?' Which kind use-case do you need? Why not directly get the token from the internal client

Comment: @dreamcrash sounds like something I am looking for. I thought that I can get the token from internal client only by password grant type. And this is opposite to my actual use case: the requirement is to provide refresh token for a client passwordlessly. Could you please tell how should I get the token from the internal client?

Comment: Have a look at client credential work flow, which type of application do you have? backend + frontend ?

Comment: Yes, it's backend + frontend application. I am not sure where to credential workflow is, but I assume that this is Authentication Flow Overrides. It's empty for both Browser flow and Direct grant flow.

Comment: You just need to go to the client select "access Type" and select 'confidential' and enable the work flow 'Service Accounts  Enabled'

Comment: The client that provides token is already set up as service account and it is confidential. But the subject_token (from my initial post) is needed to be provided by the client that needs refresh token. The issue is that one of the requirements is that requesting client should be public, not confidential. Is it possible to provide refresh token from service account confidential client to a public one without subject_token?

Comment: I don't think so